# Multiple responses for same ID - Create additional column to retain both responses

Tags: sql, select, duplicates, pivot, psql

I have a data set with multiple responses from the same person / ID (separate rows for IDs, responses in same column). I'm looking to create additional columns (either via a view or creating / updating additional columns) to retain these multiple responses in a single row. I'm assuming I need to join the table on itself and use another (sequential) ID for this? Any help would be appreciated (please see example below, apologies for formatting...).

Thanks in advance!

Current data:

```
ID      Column1
------------------------
P1      Response1 
P1      Response2 
P2      Response1 
P2      Response2
```

Desired data:

```
ID      Column1a      Column1b
--------------------------------
P1      Response1     Response2
P2      Response1     Response2
```

Comment: (1) What database you are using?  (2) Is the maximum number of responses always 2?  (3) How are the responses ordered?

Comment: (1) I honestly have no clue lol. MSSql Server? (2) In this instance, yes. But I will be doing this across tables and not sure what the max will be for those tables. (3) Responses are ordered by completion date.

Comment: In general, having repeating groups in a table is a bad database design decision. Tables that aren't in first normal form make queries more difficult to write and artificially limit the data you can hold in the table.

Answer (score 0):

One option use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation. Assuming that you want responses ordered by `completion_date`, as indicated in the comments:

```
select
    id,
    max(case when rn = 1 then column1 end) column1a,
    max(case when rn = 2 then column1 end) column1b
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by id order by completion_date) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by id
```

You can expand the `select` clause with more conditional `max()`s to handle more possible values per `id`.

Comment: Super useful! I was going to use STUFF to concatenate all the responses, then parse them out based on the delimiter. But, this is much more efficient. If I need more columns in my final table, I would just create a view and join the table on itself?

Comment: @Ian: you would probably be better off add the columns to the `selecŧ` and `group by` clauses. But I can't really tell since you did not provide this information in your question.